# unable to bind list of object properties from application.yml in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to bind a list of object properties to a field in spring bean, but spring does not bind it. What am I missing? My env is SpringBoot v2.7.1 + Java 8.

> application.yml

```
application:
  mappings:
    -   oldname: 'old name 1'
        newname: 'new name 1'
    -   oldname: 'old name 2'
        newname: 'new name 2'
```

> MappingProperties.java

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
public class MappingProperties {
    private List<Mapping> mappings;

    public List<Mapping> getServers() {
        return mappings;
    }

    public void setServers(List<Mapping> mappings) {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    public class Mapping {
        private String oldname;
        private String newname;

        public String getOldname() {
            return oldname;
        }

        public void setOldname(String oldname) {
            this.oldname = oldname;
        }

        public String getNewname() {
            return newname;
        }

        public void setNewname(String newname) {
            this.newname = newname;
        }
    }
}
```

> DemoApplication.java

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MappingProperties.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MappingProperties mappingProperties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(mappingProperties);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was being silly, I forgot to change the Getter and Setter methods name after I modified the properties, that's why the Spring cannot bind that configuration. After fixing the Getter and Setter name the binding works all right. Thank you @vladtkachuk for giving me the demo link, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`
https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

UPD: an implementation example was found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-yaml-list

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that before, but the result is the same. There seems no code examples in www.baeldung.com to binding properties from a list of own defined object. There's such configuration in the below page, but it's only configuration, there's no related XXXProperties java code in related github repo.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-yaml-vs-properties#2-list-structure-1

Comment: what do you mean with "spring does not bind it"? is it null / empty / exception?

Comment: It's null. The mappings field in mappingProperties is null.

Comment: this one demos what you are looking for imo
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-yaml-list

Comment: you're right, that's the demo I'm looking for. Thanks. I'm now checking why the demo could work but mine could not, they looks almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've had an oddly difficult time finding succinct, practical, working examples of this, so I thought I'd share a bit of code from after I pieced it together and got it working.

For some application.yml like this:

```
spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
            authorizationserver:
                client:
                    oidc-client:
                        registration:
                            client-id: "client ID value"
                            client-authentication-methods:
                                - "value 1"
                                - "value 2"
                                - "atc."
```

I created a class like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.oidc-client.registration")
public class RewindOidcConfiguration {

    private String clientId;
    public void setClientId(String value) { this.clientId = value; }

    private List<String> clientAuthenticationMethods;
    public void setClientAuthenticationMethods(List<String> value) { this.clientAuthenticationMethods = value; }

    ...

}
```

This sets the private fields which are then available for you to use as you wish.  This demonstrates hierarchy, flexible binding for the names, list values, the need for setters (which Spring calls), etc.